# How to replace OpenGL EGL14 class in android api level 16

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working on an android video calling application, which currently supports android kitkat (api level 19) . I need to add support for jelly beans(api level 16).
I have done most of the things. But i am using EGL14 class right now, which is not there in android api level 16, as it was introduced in api level 17.

I want to know how and with what to replace it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previously available version is `EGL10` from the `javax.microedition.khronos.egl` package, which has been available since API level 1. The reference page is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/egl/EGL10.html.

It is overall fairly similar, even though the Java bindings were implemented somewhat differently. And of course it does not have features from newer versions.

If you want to see examples of how typical calls look for both of them in comparison, you can check out my answer to this question here: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/egl/EGL10.html. It contains code to create a context from scratch with both versions.